# pagination and passing url parameters in php

Tags: php

I have my `index.php` page that has a form. After validation, the parameters from `index.php` are passed in the URL to another page called `test1.php`.

`test1.php` has pagination and because of that, the page keeps refreshing and my URL parameters vanish. I want my parameters to stay in `test1.php` while paginating because the parameters and the data from `test1.php` will be used in `test2.php`

```
index.php
<a href="test1.php?test=".<?php urlencode($var)?> > Go </a>

test1.php
$var1= $_REQUEST['test'];
<a href="test2.php?test=".<?php urlencode($var1)?> > Go </a>

test2.php
$param = $_REQUEST['test'];
```

Comment: Where are `$var`and `$var1` getting set?

Comment: What you want answered is not clear... You need to append your parameters to the pagination URLs on test1.php   --   ?

Comment: $var is $var = $_POST['p_name']; and var1 is $var1 = $_REQUEST['test'];

Comment: I don't want test1.php to wash out URL parameters when I paginate because I'll need those parameters in test2.php

Comment: Then you need to find the code segment in test1.php where pagination URLs are being generated and append the parameters to them.

Comment: Ok I'll try that and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are creating a variable named `$param` but using `$params` (with an "s") in your `urlencode()`

Comment: $params is just any other variable, not related to $param because $param is in another page.

Answer (score 0):

See $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  and concatenate your url with the already existing request variables.